# How to implement heatmap?

Tags: heatmap

I want to implement heatmap for our site based on our own site logs, but do not how to implement it.

My current idea is to generate an image within the click percentage as the background image.

I'd like to know whether there're some other mature solutions for heatmap implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a proper heat map, see [Recording user data for heatmap with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496267/recording-user-data-for-heatmap-with-javascript).

[Here](http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/5-heatmap-site-analytics-solutions.html) is a list of a few third-party options.

For something a bit different, [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) provides a similar feature called [In-Page Analytics](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2010/10/introducing-in-page-analytics-visual.html) which replaced the Site Overlay feature.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find that html overlay may be a proper solution for me.

Comment: Did you solve your own problem? If so, you should accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the data-driven documents, D3.js, a JavaScript library. Worth checking it out :)