# Website usage heatmap

Tags: javascript, web-applications, heatmap

I have a web application I wish to find the usage patterns for.

I wish to be able to track (and generate) usage heatmaps, I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2496550/1031900) and [ClickHeat](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html).
The problem is those are good for tracking clicks. I want to track the usage by tracking mouse cursor location.
The assumption is the mouse is mostly located where the user looks...

`onmousemove` with a sample interval is what I currently have.
Is there a JS library that does that more efficiently, or at least outside my site's code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try taking a look at this [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) by Patrick Wied. Be sure to click on the `Display Website's RealTime Heatmap` button to see it in action.

> The heatmap.js library is currently supported in Firefox 3.6+, Chrome
>   10, Safari 5, Opera 11 and IE 9+.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - Seems so: https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js

Comment: on their site they say for commercial use you need a license, afaik. someone confirm?

Comment: Yeah, that is indeed what it says here http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/get-heatmap.html. I suppose it depends on what you're looking to use it for. You can probably reach out to them at: `heatmap-q@patrick-wied.at`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a very small website or are willing to pay for this feature, you might want to check out https://mouseflow.com/. I've never used it and don't know anyone who has, but I have investigated it, and it seems like it could be something like what you're looking for.

Comment: It looks good, but I don't want to spend money on it

Comment: How many visitors does your site get per month? They do have a very limited free plan.

Comment: I have around 20 registered users for my application, with around 200 sessions per month.

Comment: MouseFlow will let you have up to 100 recorded sessions/month. See https://mouseflow.com/pricing/.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple to install and free solution is offered by etracker:

https://www.etracker.com/en/etracker-products-realtime-webanalytics-visitor-voice/etracker-visitor-motion/visitor-motion-lite.html

The free version offers 100 free page impressions per month. A heatmap isn't included, though - that's only available in the higher plans. But you can analyze the motions of each of the 100 visitors. That should give you a first impression on your visitors behaviour.