# trying to print out the mouse x and y pos on screen - getting 0,0

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling

When a user clicks anywhere on the website, I want to register the mouse x and y pos and want to print it out.

**PROBLEM: It prints out 0, 0 positions EVERY time.**

**this function gets the position of x and y**

```
    // get the position of click
function getPosition(el) {
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;
 
  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
      // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
      var xScrollPos = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      var yScrollPos = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 
      xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - xScrollPos + el.clientLeft);
      yPosition += (el.offsetTop - yScrollPos + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPosition += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }
 
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPosition,
    y: yPosition,
    a: "hahah",
  };
}
```

**on click event handler**

```
function onClickDo(event) {

 var el = event.CurrentTarget;
 var posOb = getPosition(el);

 for (var key in posOb) {
        console.log(key);
      }
     alert(posOb.x + " x pos");
     alert(posOb.y+ "  y pos");
     alert(posOb.a+ " random string");

}
```

**onload function**

```
    window.onload =  function() {
    document.onclick = onClickDo(event);

};
```

***UPDATE BASED ON ANSWER***

```
    // Set up event handlers according to modern standards
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
});

function handleClick(event) {

  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;
 var el = event.currentTarget; <----------------------- targeting the element not working

  while (el) {
    if (el.nodeName == "BODY") {
      // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
      var xScrollPos = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      var yScrollPos = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 
      xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - xScrollPos + el.clientLeft);
      yPosition += (el.offsetTop - yScrollPos + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPosition += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }
 
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
//   return {
//     x: xPosition,
//     y: yPosition,
//  a: "hahah",
//   };


 alert(xPosition + " x pos" + " and " + yPosition + "  y pos");

 }
```

*I had to define `el` using `event.currentTarget`.. however I am getting `NaN` error. No SURE. Please help!*

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax and property errors:

Change: `document.onclick = onClickDo(event);` to: `document.onclick = onClickDo;`

You do not pass the event to the event handling function. That happens automatically. And, the way your code is written, `onClicDo` is being invoked immediately instead of waiting for a click event.

Also, `event.CurrentTarget` should be: `event.currentTarget` and
`el.tagName` should be: `el.nodeName`

Here's a very scaled down version to show the basic set up.

```js
// Set up event handlers according to modern standards
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
});

function handleClick(event) {
 alert("x:" + event.offsetX + ", y:" + event.offsetY);
}
```

Comment: "onClicDo is being invoked immediately instead of waiting for a click event" - I understand that is the problem. What is the solution any ideas?

Comment: @Shaz I already gave you the solution, change the code as I have specified.

Comment: So i believe event.offsetX is relative to the parent and hence won't give me the correct cords. In the handlerClick function I made the following change. Please see the updated code in the answer. Help!

Comment: @Shaz  I only used those to show you an example of how to successfully get coordinates out of the event. There are a variety of other properties you can use to get more precise coordinates should you need them. All you have to do is substitute those properties for the ones I've shown.

Comment: The goal is to store all the click cords to database and then download the webpage in memory, take a screenshot, and display the clicks over the heat map. For this, will  event.offsetX give me the precise coordinates... since i have to take into consideration fixed widths, fluid, and elements are relative to parent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496267/recording-user-data-for-heatmap-with-javascript